"We were not able to estimate gas. There might be an error in the contract and this transaction may fail." message, but the transaction succeed
While developing a contract I got this error both in BSC Testnet and mainnet:
"We were not able to estimate gas. There might be an error in the contract and this transaction may fail." but if I ignore this message I realize, in both chains, that the transaction succeed.
I was trying to debug the issue and realized that this error happens in my metamask wallet with almost any transaction, so I went to do a simple approve to an arbitrary token, like:
https://testnet.bscscan.com/token/0xc8cf9bac05202a0e6527f2745d8d0adef7a6a8fe#writeContract
And when I click approve to a valid Ethereum address I receive the warning again,
I thought it was a problem with the RPC URL and I have tried a couple of them:
https://data-seed-prebsc-1-s2.bnbchain.org:8545
https://bsc-testnet.blockpi.network/v1/rpc/public
And the problem persists...
But in the end the tx succeed:
https://testnet.bscscan.com/tx/0x052b62e040f5317ee583472d70c7e2c9869c79280c3137c8498b08e2b3d24ba7
Any ideas?

The error says that the node cannot accurately estimage gas usage. But it doesn't necessarily the transaction will fail. Amonth others, it may occur due to network conditions (heavy load) or public RPC node limitations.
P.S. I'm a Developer Advocate at Chainstack (fast and reliable RPC nodes).
